Possibly Anime from the 2000s: Movie where a bullied kid transports into a fantasy world with a robot that becomes evil at the end
I think I was really young when I stumbled onto this movie on TV but I can't remember much about it, other than that it's most probably an anime movie from the 2000s. The story has a bullied kid, or just a shy kid, who has a poster in his room of a robot with half of his body showing his internal mechanical body, and then somehow he travels to another world and meets this very same big robot and now the kid has armor and some weapons (I don't remember what weapons clearly, but maybe a sword and a shield), and he finds a girl like a princess. Later, something happens and he figures out the robot is evil and he goes back to reality then to this fantasy world to defeat this evil robot. This is all I can manage to remember about the story; as for how it looked, it had pretty good animation (like anime feature film levels not series) and had that early 2000s look as far as i can remember
I would be really grateful if someone finds the name of this movie because I've had this movie in my head for half my life without knowing its name.

Maybe you are searching for Brave Story ?

@SebastianSiemens thanks for your suggestion! but unfortunately I clearly remember a robot as a character and villain and the poster. The look of both the films is similar tho.

I have closed your question as a duplicate, but this is not a censure, just part of our policy that story-id questions be closed as duplicates if they share an exact answer, even if the questions differ. It helps tie things together in the system for further queries.

It's a partial match, but could this be the Korean animation The Toy Warrior? I'd previously provided it as an answer here.


The Land of Toys is a world ruled by freedom and imagination, as well as the doll princess Sherbet. But the evil and mysterious Dark One arrives to threaten the peace of the toy kingdom, and to protect her world, the princess travels to the real world where she must find the heroic Warrior Prince…
But unfortunately, the only one she finds is our protagonist, Jinoo, an immature but good-hearted boy who loves toys. Jinoo believes that all of his toys are real and alive, like his best friend Ping, a stuffed animal-backpack. His favorite toy is definitely the Toy Warrior, an action figure of a hero, whom Jinoo adores and aspires to be like him.
When Jinoo accidentally touches the magical and sacred Warrior Stone, which Sherbet was carrying to choose the savior of the Land of Toys, he is transported to that magical world. Now, with the powers of being a human in the land of imagination, the help of Princess Sherbet, the police robot R.J. and a now alive Ping, must defeat the dark forces that threaten both worlds. Though the true master behind it all might be the least expected, this won't stop the new Toy Warrior from fulfilling his destiny.

The film opens on a poster of the eponymous Toy Warrior on Jinoo's wall. Said character does have a robotic appearance. And indeed, he turns out to be the villain, and there's a segment where they have to deal with him in the real world.



Oh my god I think this is it, thank you so much. As for the visuals I think I misremembered as it looking like an anime in my kid brain haha

It's a fairly anime look, being a Korean production made to appeal to American anime fans. :-D
